# Display annotation view crashes on iOS 6

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I'm working on an app that has a `MKMapView` with `annotations`. Everything works fine on iOS7, but when I try it on iOS6, as I tap on an annotation, the app crashes with :

```
 *** Assertion failure in -[MyAnnotationView layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UIView.m:5776

 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. MyAnnotationView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'
```

I've added :

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

to my `MyAnnotationView`, but nothing changes. I don't really know what to do here.

Thanks for your help !

EDIT :

I am using auto layout. I've tried to add

```
self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

in `MyAnnotationView` `init` method, but nothing changes. (I've tried with `YES` too)

Comment: Show your code please.